# Fail Installation: OpenCV 2.4.6.1 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, opencv, cuda, cmake, macports

I am frustrated with installing OpenCV 2.4.6.1 on My MacBook Pro Mountain Lion, I've tried so many ways using MacPort, CMake, Cuda to no avail.

I followed the instruction from this site http://sadeepj.blogspot.sg/2012/03/installing-and-configuring-opencv-to.html to install and configure OpenCV in MacOS X. However, when I run in the command line **'$ make'** it always results in error at [30%].

```
    [ 30%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/perf/perf_main.cpp.o
/Users/yonasstephen/Downloads/opencv-2.4.6/modules/core/perf/perf_main.cpp:3:1: error: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'argc' [-Werror,-Wunsequenced]
CV_PERF_TEST_MAIN(core)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/yonasstephen/Downloads/opencv-2.4.6/modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts/ts_perf.hpp:501:5: note: expanded from macro 'CV_PERF_TEST_MAIN'
    CV_PERF_TEST_MAIN_INTERNALS(modulename, plain_only, __VA_ARGS__)\
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/yonasstephen/Downloads/opencv-2.4.6/modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts/ts_perf.hpp:480:12: note: expanded from macro 'CV_PERF_TEST_MAIN_INTERNALS'
    while (++argc >= (--argc,-1)) {__VA_ARGS__; break;} /*this ugly construction is needed for VS 2005*/\
           ^          ~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/perf/perf_main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: This is Off-topic. http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: no, it's not ;) http://code.opencv.org/issues/3179#note-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured out how to solve this and posted it here: https://sites.google.com/site/yonasstephenfyp2013/updates/tutorialinstallingopencvonmacosxmountainlion

the essence of solving this is using the right version of OpenCV. At the time I installed, the stable version was OpenCV 2.4.3. Don't go for the latest version because it might be compatible yet with the new MacOS OS

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. While this link may contain the answer, it might not live forever. Please include the essence of it in your answer.

Comment: Ok, the essence of solving this is using the right version of OpenCV. At the time I installed, the stable version was OpenCV 2.4.3. Don't go for the latest version because it might be compatible yet with the new  MacOS OS

Answer (score 3):

you could just skip the performance tests for now. (you can always build them later, once this got solved)

add:

```
-D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF
```

to your cmake cmdline

[edit]

looks you're having issues [#3191](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3191) and 3179

both of them are fixed in 2.4 now  https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/1228 , https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/1244

when did you download the code ? might consider getting a fresh copy ?

Comment: However, there is another error at [55%] generated. Do you know how to resolve this by any chance?

[ 55%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/dpstereo.cpp.o
   
/opencv-2.4.6/modules/legacy/src/dpstereo.cpp:164:19: error: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'temp3' [-Werror,-Wunsequenced]

Comment: Fix for the latter issue is here: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/e9b9a6fc038fc243e2debcc1dabd0d0745ff39d6/diff/modules/legacy/src/dpstereo.cpp